# Shopify Product API (custom fields)

Tags: api, shopify, shopify-app

I've been exploring the Shopify Products API, specifically the return of
GET /admin/products.json

And I can't find any return of custom fields in the Response that's provided in the documentation. Is this usually provided in the API and is nested in the JSON, or do you have to do a bit of relational digging to find the custom fields? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metafields are the closest thing that Shopify has to custom fields on products. If you're using the REST API, you'll have to make a separate call to the [Metafields API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/metafield) to fetch them. You can retrieve products and their metafields in one call using the new [admin GraphQL API.](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api)

Comment: This worked for me. Appreciate the Answer!